# TTFB High for GWT-RPC Calls

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc

We are using GWT framework as our main front end. We are encountering problem with on e of the RPCS. Its TTFB ( time for first byte) is very high . Although the logs on the backend suggest that it takes 600ms to fetch data . 
However in chrome it's more than 2 sec (3.23 to be precise ) with 2.90 as TTFB

PS **Using 2.8.0 as GWT version**

[image]

Can some pls address the discrepancy here. Also any tips and suggestions on how to reduce TTFB for gwt rpcs . We are facing a hard time here .

Comment: What specifically do your backend logs measure - for example, if the payload being sent back is large (42k doesnt seem huge, but hard to tell without more context), are you measuring serialization, or just the time it takes to execute the method? Do other browsers perform as badly? Can you measure with wireshark, either at the server or at the client to see where the delay is?

Comment: At the backend of rpc we measure only the time taken in execution of process and not the time taken to serialise/ deserialise . Verified that its happening in chrome and firefox .

Comment: Measure the entire backend time - you could have too much time taken to serialize (custom field serializers with locks as an example), you could have filters taking a lot of time (commiting transaction takes a long time, or acquiring auth details?). The Time To First Byte could easily include those other things on the server, and is not likely to mean that anything is wrong with the browser (barring browser plugins, which you ruled out, or service workers, which you haven't yet).

Comment: The best place now to ask for GWT questions is to join https://gitter.im/gwtproject/gwt